# Compiling kernel module without exact kernel source

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I managed to compile my kernel module with a very similar kernel source like my Android device owns, but during the installation i get *'disagrees about version of symbol module_layout'* error message, what is an expected behavior.

I picked the binary kernel image from the device and extracted the Module.symvers file. I tried to place the extracted file to the following places:

- changed the original one in the similar kernel source's directory
- next to my module source code (after compilation it is always emptied /imho because i don't export any symbol/)

After compiling my module, the values from the newly extracted file are still not used. The modulename.mod.c file still contains the original values.

Here is my Makefile for the module:

```
KERNEL_DIR=~/android/kernels/kernel_3.4.0
obj-m += module.o
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You shouldn't need the full kernel source to compile a module.  You just need the corresponding kernel headers.  Does your distro not provide that?

Comment: It's an android kernel and i don't have the exact source code. As i read online documentations i've never seen anything like kernel headers as in various Linux distributions.

Comment: Do you have a /proc/config.gz ? Did you get a branch of the closest kernel sources at http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html ? You need to configure the kernel very similar to get your compatibility up. You might also want to switch to an android-specific compiler.

Comment: @TobySpeight: your answer only is correct for compilation on a distro for the same distro. Not for cross-compilation as is requested here.

Comment: @KlaasvanGend Sadly, i don't have /proc/config.gz. But i did my homework so the kernel can't be more similar. I'm using GCC ARM pre-built toolchain from the Android website.
But my question is aiming for the usage of the different Module.symvers file instead of finding better matching kernel source.